# How to show data that doesn't have value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and these are my tables

`pemesanan`

[image: pemesanan]

`detail_pemesanan`

[image: detail_pemesanan]

I've tried this query

```
select pemesanan.tgl_pesan, 
  SUM(detail_pemesanan.jumlah) as jumlah
FROM pemesanan 
JOIN detail_pemesanan 
 ON pemesanan.id_pemesanan = detail_pemesanan.id_pemesanan 
WHERE pemesanan.tgl_pesan >= DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -6 day) 
GROUP BY pemesanan.tgl_pesan
```

but it just show `tgl_pesan` that have value on `jumlah`.

What I want is to have all the `tgl_pesan` even though it doesn't have value on `jumlah`.  Is there any solution?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Also research different JOIN types e.g. LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, INNER JOIN (which is what it is probably defaulting to)

Comment: Thank you, sorry for my mistake @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I'm using mySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a `left join`:

```
select p.tgl_pesan, SUM(dp.jumlah) as jumlah
FROM pemesanan p JOIN
     detail_pemesanan dp
     ON p.id_pemesanan = dp.id_pemesanan 
WHERE p.tgl_pesan >= DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -6 day) 
GROUP BY p.tgl_pesan;
```

If you actually want a zero instead of `NULL`, use `COALESCE(SUM(dp.jumlah), 0)`.

Comment: but it still show the same results like what i've done

Comment: i didn't add left on join so it show the same result, sorry for my bad and thank you